# Is there a one-click widget to make my phone completely silent?

Tags: app-widgets, silent-mode

I currently use [Mute All](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.km.house.volume) but it requires several clicks. I like the ease of [Silent Toggle Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aiteam.silenttogglewidget&hl=en) but it doesn't turn of media sounds.

Ideally the widget would also turn of haptic feedback.

Comment: Related: [How can I make silent mode affect media volume too?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19158/how-can-i-make-silent-mode-affect-media-volume-too/)

Answer (score 2):

I created a Task in Tasker called Silent  that does this and created a widget that allows the one click behavior you are looking for.

Basically Silent is just a set of tasks that set the notification/ringer/system volume/etc to level 0.  Here is the XML for the Silent.tsk.xml if you want to import it.

```
<class cl="Task" sr="">
<nme>Silent</nme>
<id>14</id>
<class cl="Action" sr="act1">
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg2">
    </class>
    <code>304</code>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg1">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg0">
    </class>
</class>
<class cl="Action" sr="act0">
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg2">
    </class>
    <code>305</code>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg1">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg0">
    </class>
</class>
<class cl="AppIcon" sr="icn" ve="2">
    <icn>2130837581</icn>
</class>
<class cl="Action" sr="act4">
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg0">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <code>256</code>
</class>
<class cl="Action" sr="act5">
    <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg5" ve="2">
        <val></val>
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg4">
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg3">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg2">
        <val>3</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg1" ve="2">
        <val>Vibrate On</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="StringArg" sr="arg0" ve="2">
        <val>Vibrate On</val>
    </class>
    <code>550</code>
</class>
<class cl="Action" sr="act2">
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg2">
    </class>
    <code>308</code>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg1">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg0">
    </class>
</class>
<class cl="Action" sr="act3">
    <class cl="IntArg" sr="arg0">
        <val>1</val>
    </class>
    <code>258</code>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Audio Muter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MyApps.AudioMuter) you should be able to set the media volume to silent, however it's a paid app.

Answer (score 0):

[Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget&hl=en) (free) and [Audio Manager Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidgetpro) ($2.99) fully solve this issue very cleanly.  It gives complete control over haptic feedback and the 6 distinct audio volume controls (including media volume), and lets you construct profiles that can be toggled with one-click widgets.