# How can I make silent mode affect media volume too?

Tags: audio, silent-mode

Silent mode is simple to toggle quickly and easily, but it only effects ringtone volume. I want it to work for media volume too, so I can use it to quickly toggle off game audio in public places. Is this possible? Or is there another simple solution? I have a Google Experience phone, so manufacturer-custom UI elements are no help.

Comment: Related [Is there a one-click widget to make my phone completely silent?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13352)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[RealSilent](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.geekherd.realsilent) may do the trick for you:

```
Battery-friendly background service that will automatically mute
the media volume on your phone when you change the ringer to silent.

Features:
- Ability to mute on silent mode, as well as vibrate.
- Ability to restore media volume to what it was before going to silent/vibrate.
```

There's a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3844) for this issue, but it hasn't been acknowledged by Google.

Comment: Pulled from the app store although it still works on the latest Android version.  [Here is a github backup link](http://limeblack.github.io/a/RealSilent.1.0.1.apk)

Answer (score 1):

With [Audio Muter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=MyApps.AudioMuter) you should be able to set the media volume to silent, however it's a paid app.

Answer (score 0):

[Audio Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget&hl=en) (free) and [Audio Manager Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidgetpro) ($2.99) fully solve this issue very cleanly.  It gives complete control over haptic feedback and the 6 distinct audio volume controls (including media volume), and lets you construct profiles that can be toggled with one-click widgets.